# Have python's __init__.py file link to a class without executing the file containing it upon simple package import

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

I have a question about python's __init__.py files.

Suppose I have some package looking like that :

```
foo/
|--- foo/
     |--- __init__.py
     |--- afile.py
|--- setup.py
```

with the __init__.py looking like that

```
from .afile import MyClass
```

And afile.py looking like that :

```
print("bar")
class MyClass:
    pass
```

Suppose I have installed my package correctly and want to use it somewhere on my machine. I can then write in some script

```
import foo
```

When I do that, I get "bar" printed. That is because when I import *foo*, its __init__.py file is executed, which imports *afile.py* which executes the *print*. All that I understand and it makes sense. But what I would like to have is the following :

**NOT** having "bar" printed out when I only write

```
 import foo
```

**BUT** having it printed out when I write

```
 from foo import MyClass
```

And, of course, I **DO NOT** want to write

```
 from foo.afile import MyClass
```

-+
**IN OTHER WORDS** : I want to replace the *from .afile import MyClass* in my __init__.py file by some "link" to *MyClass* but I do not want the __init__.py to execute what *is* in afile.py.

Is it possible or am I asking too much ?

Comment: just curious: what would be the use case for this?

Comment: Hi ! Inside my package is a class that I do not use often, and that takes a few seconds upon importing because it needs to setup an access to some distant server. I do not mind waiting when I use this class, but by putting the class in the \_\_ini\_\_.py, the file containing it is executed each time I simply do ```import mypackage```, even if I do not want to use the said class.

Comment: Would it be possible to add an "init" function that sets up the server access inside afile.py?